# RegExp char escape in C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, g++, std

I use `std::regex`, next code give me exception:

```
try {
    regex rnl("\\b(sub)([^ ]*)");
} catch (regex_error& e) {
    cout << e.code() << endl;    
}
```

`e.code()` == 2, i think what problem in `\\b`. How i can create correct `regex`?

Comment: use raw strings and make your life easy `R"......"`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your regular expression, and it works fine with my copy of VS2012. The problem must be with your compiler and/or its accompanying standard library implementation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, on linux `g++ -std=c++0x -o clu++ main.cpp`

Comment: @aaronman, `error: invalid character '\' in raw string delimiter`

Comment: @dangreen - `g++ ...` is the problem. Its "implementation" of regular expressions consists of a bunch of non-functional stubs.

Comment: @PeteBecker which compiler for linux supports regexp from std ?